# Terumot and Maasrot in Israeli Shuks

Tags: kashrut-kosher, eretz-yisrael, maaser-tithes, fruits, state-of-israel

Ordinary Israeli fruit and vegetable stands do not carry teudah. Does the Israeli government ensure terumot and maasrot are taken at some point? For example, can one taste produce in Machane Yehuda or one must take the produce home and separate the various portions first?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ordinary". Some do and some don't.

Comment: Many produce stands in Machane Yehuda have kosher certification.  Moreover, even one who is careful not to rely on the Israeli Rabbinate for meat or dairy products, can eat fresh fruits and vegetables certified by the Rabbinate.  The Rabbinate's method of separating tithes is identical to any 'mehadrin' or 'badatz' certification.  The only time this is different is during shmittah, when the Rabbinate accepts heter mechira.  Then again, Eidah Charedit Yerushalayim buys from Jewish farmers in the Negev, which many other authorities rule is part of Eretz Yisrael.  Pick your poison.

Comment: @Jake That is not entirely accurate. The Mehadrin fruit Hashgachot will be more careful about certain species which may possibly be Orlah, as well as other more subtle details in the Hafrasha. I agree though that it's an overall "low risk" venture.

Comment: @DoubleAA not more careful, more stringent, but I'll admit that there are some slight differences.  The process of taking appropriate tithes is not something they differ on.  Granted, Rav Ovadia Yosef held that passionfruit is not subject to Orlah, since it gives more than one crop a year.  That doesn't mean that all passionfruit is from a vine less than four years old, but I suppose it's something that some people would avoid eating, if they knew of that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

No, the government does not ensure that *terumot* and *maasrot* are taken. Stands with a teudah are ensured by the Rabbanut.

I read in a guide for Anglos in Israel that in a case such as this where there is a doubt if the produce had been tithed, the tithes should be separated (again) without the accompanying blessings.

As for tasting food at a shuk, I've never really thought about that. I don't think it is halachically *achilat arai* (a snack), as the fruit is already *chayav* in *trumot* and *maasrot*. Therefore, it seems to me that you shouldn't do it unless you know that they have been taken off, and you have permission from the store owner.

Comment: By "is already _chayav_ in _trumot_" do you mean "is already _nikba'_ for _trumot_"?

Comment: Is there a difference in implications from each term?

Comment: The produce has already "come inside" from the field, to the packing house.  That was when the snack leniency disappeared.

Comment: @Jake Yes, that is what i said.

Comment: @Scimonster You wrote that you had never thought about it, and that you don't think it is achilat arai.  I have thought about it, and I added in a comment definitively that it isn't achilat arai.

Comment: @Jake Alright, i see the difference.

Comment: @Scimonster It's not what you said. You said they are chayav in trumot. That means if you were to, for instance, sell them to a non-Jew or maybe take them out of Israel the obligation would remain. Keva' regarding trumot is the relevant factor for allowing Achilat Arai.

Comment: @Jake That is not accurate here as the produce was being prepared to be sold so it was Nikba' already at Gemar Melacha. Going into the house is only relevant for one's personal produce.